# How to delete an item from cart?

Tags: flutter, dart

recently I have followed a `Youtube` tutorial where it shows how to add product item to cart. But in the video, it didn't show how to delete an item from cart. Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8d3qqbP3qk

`ProductModel.dart`

```
class ProductModel{
  String name;
  int price;
  String image;

  ProductModel(String name, int price, String image){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

`ProductScreen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/models/product.dart';


class ProductScreen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel> _valueSetter;

  ProductScreen2(this._valueSetter);

  List<ProductModel> products = [
    ProductModel("Grey Jacket", 100, 'assets/jacket_1.png'),
    ProductModel("Brown Pants", 60, 'assets/jeans_9.png'),
    ProductModel("Grey Pants", 50, 'assets/jeans_6.png'),
    ProductModel("Orange Pants", 70, 'assets/jeans_8.png'),
    ProductModel("Long Jeans", 80, 'assets/jeans_2.png'),
    ProductModel("Black and Blue Cap", 40, 'assets/cap_2.png'),
    ProductModel("Black Cap", 30, 'assets/cap_6.png'),
    ProductModel("Red Cap", 35, 'assets/cap_4.png'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              leading: Image.asset(
                products[index].image,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
              title: Text(products[index].name),
              trailing: Text("\RM${products[index].price}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
              onTap: (){
                _valueSetter(products[index]);
              },
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index){
            return Divider();
          },
          itemCount: products.length
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`CheckoutScreen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/screens/address/add_address_page.dart';
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';

class CheckoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final cart;

  final sum;

  CheckoutScreen(this.cart, this.sum);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(cart[index].name),
                trailing: Text("\RM${cart[index].price}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                onTap: (){

                },
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index){
              return Divider();
            },
            itemCount: cart.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
          ),
          Divider(),
          Text("Total : \RM$sum", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500), textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text("Remarks", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: ('Example: Red Cap: Free Size, Grey Jacket: UK, M Size'),
            ),
            maxLines: 5,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Text('Buy Now',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddAddressPage()));
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Text('Try Out',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
            onPressed: () => DeviceApps.openApp('com.DefaultCompany.clothestryingfunction2'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`add_to_cart.dart`

```
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/screens/CheckoutScreen.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_int2/screens/ProductScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartAppState createState() => _CartAppState();
}

class _CartAppState extends State<CartApp> {
  List<ProductModel> cart = [];
  int sum = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Add To Cart"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(text: "Products",),
              Tab(text: "Cart",),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ProductScreen2((selectedProduct){
              setState(() {
                cart.add(selectedProduct);//update
                sum = 0;
                cart.forEach((item){
                  sum = sum + item.price;
                });
              });
            }),
            CheckoutScreen(cart, sum),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to remove the selected item from cart and minus the selected item's price from the sum. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add a callback in the `CheckoutScreen`:

```dart
class CheckoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final cart;
  final sum;
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel> _valueDeleter;


  CheckoutScreen(this.cart, this.sum, this._valueDeleter);
  ...
```

After that, add the callback function when using it in the `TabBarView` in `CartApp`:

```dart
CheckoutScreen(cart, sum, (deleteProduct) {
  setState(() {
    
    // Use this loop instead of cart.removeWhere() to delete 1 item at a time 
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        if (cart[i].name == deleteProduct.name) {
          cart.removeAt(i);
          break;
       }
    }
    sum = 0;
    cart.forEach((item) {
      sum = sum + item.price;
    });
  });
}),
```

Finally, add a button in the `ListTile` within `CheckoutScreen` to initiate the `delete` action (I'm using a `Row` in `title` here for simplicity):

```dart
ListTile(
  ... 
  title: Row(
    children: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        color: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () => _valueDeleter(cart[index]),
      ),
      Text(cart[index].name),
    ],
  ),
  trailing: Text(
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that works. But can the delete action be done in `CheckoutScreen` instead of `ProductsScreen`?

Comment: @YeapWeiKang Yes, you can apply the same logic with `CheckoutScreen`. I've updated my answer for your reference

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly. One more thing, the sum is not working properly, like I have 2 products with Rm100 and Rm60 respectively, But when I delete one of them, for example the product with Rm60, the sum shows Rm60 instead of Rm100 where the sum should be Rm100. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @YeapWeiKang hmmm it works as expected at my end. Try putting a `print()` statement inside the `setter` and `deleter` function and see if they got the right item and proceed the flow correctly

Comment: Ahh I see why it isn't working for me. I removed `sum =0;` and replaced `+` sign with `-` sign. Now, Its all good. Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it. Have a nice day :D